# Joomla! 3.2 - select from table joined with result of other select

Tags: database, joomla, joomla3.2

I am trying to get results from database in Joomla, but I need to nest one `select` inside other.
I would like to obtain result of query like this:

```php
SELECT ...
FROM ...
JOIN
   (SELECT ...
   FROM ...
   WHERE ...)
ON ...
```

but using Joomla! query object

```php
$query->select('...')
   ->from('...')
   ->join('INNER', '????? ON ...');
```

What should be in place of `?????`?

Comment: http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: Yes, I have already read that but I can't see answer to the question. Could you tell me where can you see answer?

Comment: If you look at [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Selecting_Records_from_Multiple_Tables), you will see the `INNER` part of the query which contains `$db->quoteName('#__users', 'b')` before the `ON`

Comment: This is not solution for my problem. I need to put `SELECT` query in place of `$db->quoteName('#__users', 'b')` from example quoted by you. Raw sql statement should work but I want to use query object in order to make DBMS independent code.

Comment: Make a separate instance of a query from the same dbo ... $query2 ... set up that query and they use a __toString that you set equal to another variable .. then add that string inside the parentheses.

Remember all you are doing is building up a long string that will be your query, so you can build it from different parts that you create.

Comment: @Elin , your solution is this what I need. You should post it as answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to `join` or `union`?

- **`Join`** adds a table to the result set to pull some records off it i.e. **adds columns to your result**;
- **`Union`** adds the results of two queries having the same number of columns i.e. **adds rows to your result**.

This terminology applies both in Joomla *and* in sql.

```
$query1->select('somefield')
   ->from('sometable')

$query2->select('somefield')
   ->from('anothertable')
   ->union($query1);
```

`union` supports another syntax as well:

```
$query->union('SELECT name FROM #__foo')

$query->union(array('SELECT name FROM #__foo',
    'SELECT name FROM #__bar'))
```

Also checkout the `unionDistinct` method, it might be helpful.

If you want to join, the syntax is:

```
$query->select(array('a.field1','b.field2'))->from('table1 AS a')->join('inner','table2 as b')
```

and you have shorthand methods:

- `$query->innerJoin()`
- `$query->leftJoin()`
- `$query->outerJoin()`
- `$query->rightJoin()`

Comment: I wanted to `join`.

Answer (score 1):

Coming very late, but I had the very same problem and solved it in a different way: in the `JOIN` section of the query, I inserted another query with another handle. If the query I need to run is something like

```
    SELECT
        st.*, m.measures
    FROM tbl_stations st
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT
            station_id, count(*) AS measures
        FROM tbl_measures
        GROUP BY station_id
    ) m ON m.station_id = st.id
```

then I create the handles for the two query elements

```
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$innerSelect = $db->getQuery(true);
```

and then I create the joomla part of the query:

```
$query
    ->select(array('st.*', 'm.measures'))
    ->from($db->quoteName('#__stations', 'st'))
    //here starts the inner join part (note the opening parenthesis)
    ->innerJoin('(' . 
        //I perform a canonical select using the second handle
        $innerSelect
        ->select($db->quoteName('station_id'))
        ->select('count(*) as measures')
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__measures'))
        ->group($db->quoteName('station_id'))
       //after closing the parenthesis I put an alias for the join
       //and then I have the "ON" clause of the join
    . ') ' . $db->quoteName('m') . ' ON ' . $db->quoteName('m.station_id') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('st.id'))
;
```

This is it. The final query (by the way, you can echo it using the method `$query->dump()`) is the following

```
SELECT st.*,m.measures
FROM `tbl__stations` AS `st`
INNER JOIN (
SELECT `station_id`,count(*) as measures
FROM `tbl__measures`
GROUP BY `station_id`) `m` ON `m`.`station_id` = `st`.`id`
```

Hope this can be of help to anyone passing by with the same doubt about using `SELECT` inside `JOIN`s.

Comment: It should work how I wanted to, but it claims that Joomla is poor in SQL. It is much easier to use raw SQL query than building these objects, moreover (I am not sure) I think these are two queries so it will do two requests to DB, in raw SQL we can build very complex query which will "ask" DB only once.

Comment: @kampro: absolutely right, this was just an idea of how to build a complex query. Don't forget you could just use your own plain-SQL complex query and then execute it using the common Joomla's function this way: `$db->execute($myPlainSqlQueryInAString);`. And if you feel happy, you could even use Joomla's quote/quoteName functions to escape column names and values while building your query ^^